# Play video through URL link

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I'm trying to play a youtube video through my app to test for videos that will need linked later (no videos to link yet). I'm trying everything from a UIImageView to UIWebView using MPMoviePlayer. It starts the player, then stops seconds later with the following in the log:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd:
{
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}

_itemFailedToPlayToEnd:(null)
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong as I've not that much experience with streaming videos into my apps. Thanks for the help.

```
-(void)playMovie:(id)sender
{
    UIWebView *video1 = [UIWebView new];
    video1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 60, 60);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9bBQRWkV8M"];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.player];
    mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
    [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
    [self.player setFullscreen:YES];
    self.player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.player prepareToPlay];

}
```

Comment: how you are playing the video, post your code here.

Comment: It's the link. I need to find out how to get the proper youtube link.

Comment: if you are using a web view , then why mpmovieplayer? just load the url in webview , that will work fine.

Comment: I changed it to an imageview actually, it's working now with the different formatted link, the youtube link just wouldn't work.

Comment: imageview really? how you are able to play a video with imageview .

Comment: Lol, got my lines mixed up. It's not an imageview, but a button that opens the mediaplayer fullscreen. No harry potter magic here, sorry for the confusion.